# NodeJS SQL Server tedious TypeError: columns.forEach is not a function

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious

I am trying to use the tedious driver based on some examples to process the result set from SQL Server, but always get the "TypeError: columns.forEach is not a function" error and I can not figure out why it is not working for me.

All modules are installed recently from npm (2018.09.21). tedious version: tedious@2.6.4

Example sources: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-2017

https://sqlchoice.azurewebsites.net/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/node/sles/step/2.html

My Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
var auth = require(__dirname +'/../lib/' + 'authorization');

const config = {
  server : 'servername',
  domain : 'MYDOMAIN',
  userName : 'MYUSER',
  password : 'MYPASSWORD',
  options : {
    rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion : true,
    database : 'MYDB',
    encrypt : true,
    connectionTimeout : 1000,
    requestTimeout : 0,
    useColumnNames : true,
    isolationLevel : 'READ_UNCOMITTED',
    appName : 'My nodejs app',
    connectionRetryInterval : 5000
  },
};

var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
require('tedious').ISOLATION_LEVEL;

var connection;

router.post('/', auth.auth, async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    connection = new Connection(config);
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {
      if (err)
      {
        console.log(new Date().toUTCString() + ' : Database connection failed to database : ' + config.options.database);
      }
      else
      {
          console.log(new Date().toUTCString() + ' : Database connected : ' + this.config.server + '.' + this.config.options.database + ' Status : ' + this.state.name);
          getList(res);
      }
    })
    .on('infoMessage', infoError)
    .on('errorMessage', infoError)
    .on('end', end)
    .on('debug', debug)
    .on('error', error)
    .on('databaseChange', databaseChange)
  }
  catch  (ex)
  {
    console.log(new Date().toUTCString() + ' : ' + 'Error: ' + ex.message);
    res.status(500);
    res.send(ex.message);
  }
});

function getList(res){
  var query = "SELECT * FROM sysfiles;";

  var request = new Request(query, function (err, rowCount, rows)
  {
    if (err)
    {
      console.log(new Date().toUTCString() + ' : ' + 'Error: ' + err);
      res.write('{ "error" : "' + err + '" }');
      res.end();
    }
    else
    {
      // console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
      var rowarray = [];
      rows.forEach(function(columns)
      {
        var rowdata = new Object();
        columns.forEach(function(column)
        {
          rowdata[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
        });
        rowarray.push(rowdata);
      })

      res.contentType('application/json');
      retval = JSON.stringify(rowarray);
      //if (cb)
      //{
      //  retval = cb + '(' + retval + ');'
      //}
      res.write(retval);
      res.end();
    }
  // request.on('columnMetadata', columnMetadata);
  });

  request.on('done', requestDone);
  // request.addParameter('Pattern', TYPES.VarChar, '%' + pattern +'%');
  // request.addParameter('TOP', TYPES.Null, null);

  connection.execSql(request);
  // connection.callProcedure(request);
}

module.exports = router;
```

The error message I get:

```
C:\mypath\myapp\routes\route1.js:60

        columns.forEach(function(column)

                ^

TypeError: columns.forEach is not a function
    at C:\mypath\myapp\routes\route1.js:60:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Request.userCallback (C:\mypath\myapp\routes\route1.js:57:12)
    at Request._this.callback (C:\mypath\myapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:60:27)
    at Connection.endOfMessageMarkerReceived (C:\mypath\myapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1922:20)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\mypath\myapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1004:38)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\mypath\myapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:805:18)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\mypath\myapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:54:15)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:182:13)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect
```

### Update

As "Matt Kuhn" and "Think - Twice" pointed out, the issue was with the type of the columns. Thanks to them!

The issue was the "useColumnNames : true" in the config.options section. Removing it solved the issue. We can use then "useColumnNames : true" but then we need to reference the columns by name(s) instead of walking through an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't call the request.on event that tedious exposes. You can also test to make sure that columns is an array by calling typeof. Your error means that columns is not an array, in fact is probably undefined.

Here is the code from the minimal example on their site:

```
function executeStatement() {
  request = new Request("SELECT * FROM sysfiles", function(err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
    }

    connection.close();
  });

  request.on('row', function(columns) {
    console.log("columns", columns);  //should show your array
    console.log("typeof columns", typeof columns); //should by array
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
      if (column.value === null) {
        console.log('NULL');
      } else {
        console.log(column.value);
      }
    });
  });

  request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {
    console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
  });

  // In SQL Server 2000 you may need: connection.execSqlBatch(request);
  connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Comment: Matt,Then I get the same error at the row function "columns.forEach"

Comment: Matt, the typeof columns is object, the columns list out the object as json (not as json array), then it errors our on forEach again. But, I have an earlier code(other exercise)  that works as expected, it still shows object for columns, but displays a JSON array as expected. So the issue is in my code, now I just have to figure out the difference. I will post it when I find it. thanks for the debug lines, it pointed to me to the right direction.

Comment: Matt, Thanks for the help! I found the issue. It was the useColumnNames = true in the config.options section. The hint about the type of the columns pushed me to the right direction. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check columns whether it is an array or undefinedbefore doing forEach

```
  rows.forEach(function(columns)
  {
    var rowdata = new Object();
    if(columns){
       columns.forEach(function(column)
        {
           rowdata[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
        });
    }
    rowarray.push(rowdata);
  });
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the hint! I checked and it is not null and not an array.

Comment: If it is not an array then you can do forEach on it. Can you do typeOf columns and let me know its type

Comment: Thanks! I marked bot as answer as both of you pointed me the right direction. It was indeed the type of the columns changed by the "useColumnNames = true" in the config.options. Thanks again!